# Linux PHP5 mssql_connect() to SQL Server 2005

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, windows-server-2003, ubuntu-10.10

I have php5 installed on an ubuntu 10.10 server from which I am trying to connect via mssql_connect() to a SQL Server 2005 database running on a Windows 2003 Server. I am getting an error which I believe is because the SQL Server 2005 instance is using the 'Windows Authentication' login method.  The error is:

```
Warning: mssql_connect(): message: Login failed for user 'lv_admin'. (severity 14) in /var/www/AOI/collectserials.php on line 17
```

The error log in the SQL Server database shows the following:

```
Login failed for user 'lv_admin'. [CLIENT: (ip of my php server)] 
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
```

Where lv_admin is the username logged into the Windows 2003 server so I'm not sure what the problem is...

PHP:

```
$con = mssql_connect("128.251.xxx.xx", 'lv_admin', '[mypass]');
mssql_select_db("itf", $con);
```

I need some help solving this issue..

Comment: Perhaps these 2 articles might give you a nudge in the right direction: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php   and   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296205(v=sql.90).aspx . Especially mind the comments that mention mssql_* function are deprecated and won't work anymore as of PHP5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually figured out my problem.  With Windows Authentication I still need to have the username used in the remote script commands specified in the SQL Server Users location.  Once I added lv_admin as an 'SQL Authenticated' user in the Security->Logins section I could get a valid connection to the server but the connection to the database failed.  So I went into the 'itf' database->Security->Users and added lv_admin there also specifying the privileges I needed and it worked.  Hope this saves someone else tons of time!